# jquery img class overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add red overlay on my image-box class, but I can't get the result because:
 new `overlay` class replaces the old one, and I only get red background.
I need the new class in addition to, not instead of the old one.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.wrapper', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.wrapper');
    
 target.find('.image-box').addClass("overlay");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.image-box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
}

.overlay{
 background-color:rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.55);
 transition: 0.5s;
 filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image-box"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try using background-color:rgba(86, 61, 124); only

Comment: Give width to the class overlay.

Comment: adding a class does not create a new element, it uses the same element. and an element can only have one background-color. can use pseudo elements (:before or :after) to create a layer with the same dimensions and a different and transparent background-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use :after to add overlay. Check the updated Code.

```js
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.wrapper', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.wrapper');
    
 target.find('.image-box').addClass("overlay");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.image-box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
  position: relative
}
.image-box:after {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.55);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
.overlay:after {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image-box"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is ok, but overlay goes on elements after wrapper class, is it wrong to add max-height to overlay class, or is there better solution?

Comment: do you have idea why with this code transition dont work?

Comment: Check it now. I have changed the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you better below is the code snippet.

```js
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.wrapper', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.image-box').addClass("overlay");
  });
});
```

```css
.image-box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
}

.overlay{
 /*background-color:rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.55);*/
  background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
 transition: 0.5s;
 filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image-box"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the .overlay & image-box property

```
.image-box{
 /* add position:relative */
}
.overlay{
position:absolute; background-color:red; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity: 0.8; height: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1; z-index: 9; position: absolute; top: 0; opacity: 0.5;transition: 0.5s; 
}
```

While clicking on image-box, it will give you the overlay over the image-box